# How to scale existing coordinates data in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I have a plot with its data, for example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[%multiply x data by a factor here, multiply y data by another factor
] plot[] coordinates{
 ( 1, 2 )
 ( 2, 3 )
 ( 3, 4 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I want `pgfplots` to apply a transformation (in a per-plot basis) to the data.

How do I scale (or more generally transform) the data before plotting?

If possible, this should work for `coordinates`, and be an option for `addplot[...]` or `plot[...]`

I tried `x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*scalefactor}\pgfmathresult},` but that only seems to work for the full axis and not for each curve in the plot.

The effect, should be in the example above, the same as having:

```
...
coordinates{
 ( 100., 0.2 )
 ( 200., 0.3 )
 ( 300., 0.4 )
};
...
```

Comment: It's much more comfortable if you use `\addplot table` instead of `\addplot coordinates`. Do you have a particular reason for preferring the latter?

Comment: @Jake, ideally I would like a solution that works both with `table` and `coordinates`, to reprocess source files that are already there and I want to change units of those plots.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use an `x filter/.code` to transform the x coordinates on a per plot basis. This also works if you use `\addplot table` instead of `\addplot coordinates`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*100}\pgfmathresult},
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*10}\pgfmathresult}
    ] coordinates{
 ( 1, 2 )
 ( 2, 3 )
 ( 3, 4 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you can provide your data in tabular form instead of as a coordinate list, things get more comfortable, since you can then simply use `x expr=\thisrow{X} * 100, y expr=\thisrow{Y} * 10`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x expr=\thisrow{X}*100, y expr=\thisrow{Y}*10] {
 X Y
 1 2
 2 3
 3 4
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: at the same time the first solution is more general since works both for `coordinates` and `table`

Comment: @alfC: That's true. For new plots, however, I don't think there's any reason to prefer `coordinates` over `table`. Plus, `\addplot table` allows you to provide the data either inline or in a data file.

Comment: If you find strange error messages after trying this solution try with `\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*10}\pgfmathresult`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/very-strange-interaction-between-addlegendentry-and-y-filter-in-pgfplot

Comment: Note for LaTeX beginners (like me): If you would like to scale down the data, `\thisrow{Y}/10` won't work. You have to use `\thisrow{Y}*(1/10)`.

Comment: @ComFreek: `\thisrow{Y}/10` works fine for me. Are you using an old version of PGFPlots, by any chance?

Comment: @Jake I'm using PGF 2.10 (compatiblity mode set to 1.9). I think I discovered the problem: the use of empty fields with `\thisrow{y}/10` throws an error. See http://pastebin.com/KYTBmjRk