# Strange interaction between `addlegendentry` and `y filter` in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, legend

From this answer [How to scale existing coordinates data in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/how-to-scale-existing-coordinates-data-in-pgfplots) I am using `y filter` to process data, all fine until I decide to put a legend entry in the plot. I cannot seem to simultaneously use the `yfilter` and the `addlegendenty` lines in the following code.

I get this error

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfplots@curplotlist.
```

from this code (later try commenting the two lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*10.}\pgfmathresult}% try comment
] coordinates {
 ( 1., 1. )
 ( 2., 2. )
 ( 3., 3. )
};
\addlegendentry{Legend Entry};% try comment
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What is wrong, is this a bug?

info: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013061217  (TeX Live 2013)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that this is due to a somewhat quirky behaviour of `x filter` that's described in the manual:

> Note that you can provide different `x filter`/`y filter` arguments to
>   each `\addplot` command. It seems there are only problems with the `#1`
>   argument, and I haven’t yet found out why. Please use `\pgfmathresult`
>   in place of `#1` if you provide `\addplot[x filter/.code={...}]`.

So if you change your code to use

```
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*10.}\pgfmathresult}
```

instead of

```
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*10.}\pgfmathresult}
```

everything works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addlegendentry{Legend Entry};
\addplot[
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*10.}\pgfmathresult}
] coordinates {
 ( 1., 1. )
 ( 2., 2. )
 ( 3., 3. )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops too fast to answer then :) But I'm insisting on the `addlegendentry` order. It will break if other fancy stuff enters

Comment: @percusse: Do you mean that `\addlegendentry` has to appear after the corresponding `\addplot` command? Do you have an example where things fail if you don't do that? It was my understanding that each `\addplot` command simply added its drawing style to a list, and each `\addlegendentry` added its text to a different list, and at the very end, the two lists are combined to form the legend, so the order of `\addplot` and `\addlegendentry` wouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant and I think I have one example at home. It should probably to do with forget plot issue somewhere shifting the line style or something. I am not really clear on what the issue was.