# How to scale both data and error bars in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I am able to scale the data using the `y filter` option in pgfplots plot object (like here [How to scale existing coordinates data in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/how-to-scale-existing-coordinates-data-in-pgfplots)). However the error bars are not rescaled as expected. Is there a workaround for this?

In this example, the "original" y-value is 1+/-0.5, after `y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*10}\pgfmathresult}` the data shows as 10+/-0.5 (instead of the expected 10+/-5.)

[image]

The complete code follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    only marks, 
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*1}\pgfmathresult}, 
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*10}\pgfmathresult}
] plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
 ( 1, 1 ) +- ( 0, 0.5)
 ( 2, 1 ) +- ( 0, 0.5)
 ( 3, 1 ) +- ( 0, 0.5)
 ( 4, 1 ) +- ( 0, 0.5)
} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

NOTE: `x error filter/.code = ...` is not valid code apparently.

Comment: In your real application, do you provide the coordinates in this form `(x,y) +- (xerror, yerror)`, or do you use a table?

Comment: @Jake, I use the `() +- ()` notation so I don't have to invent a name for the columns and I think it is more self descriptive than a table with names that I have to be interpreted by some `addplot` option like `x expr=\thisrow{X}` (or something like that). Having said that, if I have to switch to table, so be it.

Comment: With `\addplot table`, altering the data on the fly is simple `x error expr=\thisrow{xerror}*10`. With the `() +- ()` I don't know how to alter the error values.

Comment: @Jake, I think it would be nice to have for completeness `x error filter` and a `y error filter`.

Comment: Sounds as if `pgfplots` should add the error to the input coordinate and apply the filter to the result... that would solve the problem without the need of an additional set of filters (which would contain almost the very same transformation). Would be an incompatible change in behavior, though...

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, yes, unless you call the old behavior a bug :) OR add a new key `x scale filter` OR use the `compat` mechanism. (?)

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, maybe it has to do with this behavior http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184092/log-plot-and-x-filter-not-interacting-well-in-pgfplots ?