# log scale plot and filter not interacting well in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

It looks like when I try to scale coordinate data in a `pgfplots`, I cannot do it in log scale simply, since the expression filter seems to be applied to the final point and not the table value.

For example, I expect these two commands to produce basically the same plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log] % ymode=normal works well!
\addplot+[] table[
x expr=\thisrow{X}*1., y expr=\thisrow{Y}*3, row sep=\\
]{
X Y \\
1 1.1 \\
2 11 \\
3 110 \\
} node[]{};
\addplot+[x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*1.}\pgfmathresult}, 
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*3.}\pgfmathresult}] 
plot coordinates
{
 ( 1, 1 )
 ( 2, 10)
 ( 3, 100)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However I get this,

[image: wrongplot]

where the red line (`coordinates` version) is not the expected result. For example the last red point is about 10^6 and not about 300.

(Using `ymode=normal` produces the expected graph)

Obviously `y filter/.code` is not doing what I expected. I remember reading something about this in the manual. Maybe it is by design.

The question is: **Is there another way of applying this transformation so it works for linear and log plot (just changing the value of `ymode`)? Or I have to switch to the `plot table`-based code altogether?**

Comment: In logarithmic plots, `\pgfmathresult` is already the log of the coordinate in the filter. So it needs `\pgfmathresult+log10(3))` instead of a multiplication.

Comment: @percusse, ok but can I apply/access the data point "earlier".

Comment: I think it would be best to switch to `\addplot table` based plots, since they're more powerful and in my opinion also more convenient. Do you have a particular reason for wanting to stick with `\addplot coordinates`?

Comment: @Jake, yes. It is mostly historical reason. I think I am going to use `table` exclusively from now on, since I always find `coordinates` to behave oddly with respect to transformations (I need the feature to convert units in plots). For example another "problem"/odd behavior I found is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154084/how-to-scale-both-data-and-error-bars-in-pgfplots

Comment: The reason why it is not that easy is because coordinate input is accumulated directly, so you can use an inverse transformation but it won't be as easy as changing the ymode (you can build your own style of course but tedious nevertheless). I would also recommend switching to tables. Coordinate parsing is faster but as you noticed limited in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution. For ymode=log the default is for natural log, `basis e`, not for base 10. To work for `log10`, the axis option `log basis y=10` is required

```
\begin{axis}[ymode=log,log basis y=10] ... \end{axis}
```

Also `log (ab/cd) =log a+ log b -log c- log d` so the OP's filter code is incorrect

```
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*3.}\pgfmathresult}
```

The demonstration is for natural log, `ln`; For `log10`, one needs to add the aforementioned skill accordingly and `\pgfmathresult+log10(3)` in the filter code.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log] % ymode=normal works well!
\addplot+[] table[
x expr=\thisrow{X}*1., y expr=\thisrow{Y}*3, row sep=\\
]{
X Y \\
1 1.1 \\
2 11 \\
3 110\\
} node[]{};
\addplot+[%x filter/.code= {\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*1.}\pgfmathresult}, 
y filter/.code= {\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+ln(3)}\pgfmathresult}
] 
plot coordinates
{
 ( 1, 1)
 ( 2, 10)
 ( 3, 100)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the workaround. From an interface point of view it would be good to have a way to do it that allow to purely change `y mode` without worrying to change the parsing.