# Two plots, change bar plot reference system only

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

**TL;DR** How can I make a horizontal bar plot with the origin on the right?

I wanted to combine several plots in a unique figure. I have a custom scatter plot, and I want to overlay it on top of a bar plot, but I need to place the bars on the right, like this:

[image: Combined scatter plot/bar plot]

I want the bars there **just for visualization, the *x*-axis is only for the scatter plot.** The values for the bars are computed externally. The ideal solution would be to have a filled `const plot mark mid`, rotated, to fill in the space on the right and remove the spacing between the bars.

I didn't find any information about rotating `const plot mark mid` or about changing the whole reference system for the bar plot. I tried to adopt [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/how-to-scale-existing-coordinates-data-in-pgfplots) approach, adding `x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{-#1}\pgfmathresult}` to the `xbar` plot, but it changed the reference system also on the scatter plot. Any help would be appreciated.

**Details about the plots:** The scatter plot is weighted, and the bar plot represents the distribution of the *y*-values (it sums up all the weighted contributions of the point in one horizontal corridor).

For completeness, this is a working example of the code (that produces left-aligned horizontal bars though):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot+[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit,
        scatter/use mapped color={fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5, draw=black},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=1+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/100},
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={
          \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt> 200pt
            \node[draw=black, fill=black, inner sep=0, shape=circle, minimum size=1] at (0pt,0pt) {};
          \fi
          \endscope
        }
      ] table [x=x, y=y, meta=n] {
        x          y         n
        1.00       2.00      22.36
        1.13       1.49      131.78
        1.14       0.36      1189.32
        1.22       0.99      449.04
        1.33       0.50      1.96
        1.33       1.32      48.04
        1.33       2.00      3.92
        1.34       1.66      60.80
        1.39       0.94      330.23
        1.42       1.31      145.24
      };
      \addplot+[xbar] table[x=score, y=key]{
        key       score
        0.24      16.57
        0.44      0.02
        0.63      1.04
        0.83      27.24
        1.02      44.29
        1.22      12.36
        1.41      20.21
        1.61      10.23
        1.80      2.14
        2.00      8.90
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I found a much cleaner solution, *just use two different `axis` environments inside the same `tikzpicture`*. It doesn't even require to change the histogram source. The only detail to take care of is **setting the same y range** and **tweak `xmin` in the `xbar interval` plot** to shrink it to the right side. The trick uses `x expr` to make all the values in the bar plot negative, and display them right to left.

[image: Result with two axis]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{width=12cm, height=8cm}

    \begin{axis}[
      xbar interval,
      axis y line*=right, % Put everything on the right, in case you want markers
      axis x line=none, % No x axis
      grid=none, % No disturbing gridlines
      ticks=none, % No ticks, it's just rough visualisation
      ymin=0, ymax=2, % MANUALLY SET SAME RANGE
      xmin=-2 % MANUALLY SHRINK THE GRAPH
    ]
      % Inverx coordinate
      \addplot+ table [x=score, y=key, x expr=-\thisrow{score}] {
     score         key
    0.8174         2
    0.8174       1.6
    0.3967       1.2
         0       0.8
    0.4894       0.4
    0.6977         0
      };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line*=left,
      xmin=0, xmax=15,
      ymin=0, ymax=2 % MANUALLY SET SAME Y-RANGE
    ]
      \addplot+[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit,
        scatter/use mapped color={fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5, draw=black},
        % Changed the size of the marker to respect ``meta == c * area of the circle''
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=1+sqrt(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/pi)/2},
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={
          \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt> 200pt
            \node[draw=black, fill=black, inner sep=0, shape=circle, minimum size=1] at (0pt,0pt) {};
          \fi
          \endscope
        }
      ] table [x=x, y=y, meta=n] {
         x         y         n
     1.424    0.7382     328.7
     2.659     1.065     348.3
     4.082     1.174       142
     5.452     1.438     19.01
         6       0.5 0.0005244
     6.539      1.55        11
      7.55     1.771         5
     8.889     1.816         6
     10.75     1.905         4
     12.75     1.854         4
     45.22    0.7315         2
     47.13    0.4375         1
     50.11     1.222         1
     60.61    0.6087         1
     86.86     1.143         1
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT: Old clumsy solution.** I managed to do it in a very dirty way; I hope that someone can come out with a better trick than this. PGFPlots is awesome in many ways, but this seems not to be one. 
So, using the options `x filter` and `x expr` in any plot among `histogram`, `xbar`, `xbar interval` was breaking the layout of the `scatter` plot. I had to use the library `fillbetween` and edit the coordinates manually. Using it directly with `const plot` is impossible because `const plot` plots a function of x, and I didn't manage to rotate the plots without creating a new `axis`.

Having control on the source data, I made the program output the *coordinates of the points of the histogram*, meaning (in "pseudopython"):

```
# assume that the distribution is normalized.
# histogram_intervals is the list of bins and size as tuple (min, max, score)
# and it's sorted by min ascending.
print(1.0, histogram_intervals[-1][1])
for rg_min, rg_max, score in reverse(histogram_intervals):
     print(1.0 - score, interval_max)
     print(1.0 - score, interval_min)
print(1.0, histogram_intervals[-1][0])
```

The points must be in order *from top to bottom*, because the `fillbetween` library will not read them correctly otherwise and will "twist" the filling in the middle (see last figure).

Now, drawing these coordinates as a scatter plot, will give you the actual histogram, with the bars from left to right, in the rectangle `(0, min) rectangle (1, max)`. The idea is then to shift this to the right with `xshift` (possibly scaling it with `xscale`), and then fill in the region between that graph and a vertical line on the right side of the graph. This presumes that *you manually set the x-domain of the graph*.

Fully working example:

[image: Worked example scatter + reversed xbar interval]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{width=12cm, height=8cm}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=15]
      \addplot+[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit,
        scatter/use mapped color={fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5, draw=black},
        % Changed the size of the marker to respect ``meta == c * area of the circle''
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=1+sqrt(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/pi)/2},
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={
          \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt> 200pt
            \node[draw=black, fill=black, inner sep=0, shape=circle, minimum size=1] at (0pt,0pt) {};
          \fi
          \endscope
        }
      ] table [x=x, y=y, meta=n] {
         x         y         n
     1.424    0.7382     328.7
     2.659     1.065     348.3
     4.082     1.174       142
     5.452     1.438     19.01
         6       0.5 0.0005244
     6.539      1.55        11
      7.55     1.771         5
     8.889     1.816         6
     10.75     1.905         4
     12.75     1.854         4
     45.22    0.7315         2
     47.13    0.4375         1
     50.11     1.222         1
     60.61    0.6087         1
     86.86     1.143         1
      };
      % Add the histogram plot, with no drawing and no filling
      \addplot+[
        name path global=myhistogram,
        xscale=2,    % MANUAL TWEAK SCALE
        xshift=40mm, % MANUAL TWEAK SHIFT
        draw=none, no marks, fill=none
      ] table [x=x, y=y] {
         x         y
         1         2
    0.8174         2
    0.8174       1.6
    0.3967       1.6
    0.3967       1.2
         0       1.2
         0       0.8
    0.4894       0.8
    0.4894       0.4
    0.6977       0.4
    0.6977         0
         1         0
      };
      % Pick a vertical line at the right of the plot
      % NOTE: MANUALLY PICK AXIS COORDINATES
      \path[name path=myaxis] (axis cs: 14, 0) -- (axis cs:14, 2);
      % Draw the region.
      \addplot+ [draw=red, fill=red!50] fill between[of=myaxis and myhistogram];
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is what happens if you export your data bottom-to-top:

[image: Reversed data cause twist in filling]